# Someone solve my npm and yarn errors. I can not install anything

Tags: npm, yarnpkg

This is the error I get whenever I try to install anything with yarn

```
info No lockfile found.
[1/4] Resolving packages...
error An unexpected error occurred: "https://registry.yarnpkg.com/loader-utils: error:1E08010C:DECODER routines::unsupported".
info If you think this is a bug, please open a bug report with the information provided in "C:\\Users\\Urvah\\Downloads\\Stuff\\WebDevelopement\\yarn-error.log".
info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/install for documentation about this command.
```

And when I use NPM, this is the error I get whenever I install anything.

````
npm WARN config Use registry scoped `keyfile` and `certfile` instead.
npm WARN config     Example:
npm WARN config     //other-registry.tld/:keyfile=/path/to/key.pem
npm WARN config     //other-registry.tld/:certfile=/path/to/cert.crt
[..................] - idealTree:WebDevelopement: sill idealTree buildDeps```
I am stuck here and after 15 min, it says ERR__OS_UNSUPPORTED.

I tried everything but nothing worked.
````

Answer (score 0):

Try the following :

```
yarn install --registry=https://registry.yarnpkg.com/
```

Comment: I still get the same error
yarn install v1.22.19
info No lockfile found.
[1/4] Resolving packages...
error An unexpected error occurred: "https://registry.yarnpkg.com/loader-utils: error:1E08010C:DECODER routines::unsupported".
info If you think this is a bug, please open a bug report with the information provided in "C:\\Users\\Urvah\\Downloads\\Stuff\\WebDevelopement\\yarn-error.log".
info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/install for documentation about this command.